# Would changing the applicationId of a published Android application from com.example.exampleApp to com.example.exampleapp cause issues?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

So I have a React Native Android application with applicationId of com.example.exampleApp, however, react-native-auth0 is not working because of the capitalisation in the applicationId, which is why I am wondering if changing the capitalisation of the applicationId of an already published application would cause issues?

According to the Android documentation, once I've published my app, I should never change the application ID. If I change the application ID, Google Play Store would treat the upload as a completely different app.

Is this valid if I'm just changing the capitalisation of the applicationId?

Comment: You can try it yourself. Install the app on a device, then change capitalisation of packageName and install that app. You should end up with the app installed twice.